# Initial value problem: Solution blows up conditions

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the differential equation in $\mathbb R$:
$$x' = x^2-\lambda x^3; \,\,\,\,\,\, x(0) = x_0; \,\,\,\,\,  t\geq 0$$
where  $\lambda $ is a parameter. For which initial conditions is the solution bounded for $t\geq  0$? For which initial conditions does the solution blowup in finite time?

I notice that $x=0$ and $x=1/{\lambda}$ are boundaries for solutions. I think as long a $x_0$ is in between the $0$ and $1/{\lambda}$  for ${\lambda} \ne 0$ then the solution is bounded in between there and it cannot escape.

Comment: Please consider editing your question with some work you have done and explain where exactly you are stuck

Comment: @ Jean Thank you for your comment. I will try to think this over as I go

Comment: **Hint:** Rewrite your equation as $$x' = x^2(1-\lambda x)$$ and see what happens in the _phase line_.

Comment: @ pragahava I actually had that in my mind, that's how I came with the lines x=0 and x=1\{\lambda}.

Comment: @Klara What can you say about the cubic $x^2(1-\lambda x)$ as $\lambda$ varies? How will the sign of $x'$, and hence the nature of the critical points will change?

Comment: @ pragabhava Thank you, I added my thoughts up. I still have ways to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $\lambda =0$, $x'=x^2>0$ then IVP's solutions **blow up** for $x_0>0$ and are **bounded** for  $x_0<0$

If $\lambda <0 $, for $x_0 \in [1/\lambda, 0]$ solutions are bounded. For $x_0 >0, x'>0 $ and  $x_0 <1/\lambda, x'<0 $ all the solutions **blow up**.

If $\lambda >0 $, for $x_0 \in [0,1/\lambda]$ solutions are bounded. For $x_0 <0, x'>0 $ and  $x_0 >1/\lambda, x'<0 $ all the solutions **are bounded.**